# count vowels, consonants and numeric

Tags: c#, winforms

What's wrong with my code? If I enter `aaa`, it returns `3` in the vowels row, but if I enter `abc`, it return `3` also in the vowels row.

By the way, it's a windows form .

```
txtInputString.SelectionStart = 0;
txtInputString.SelectionLength = txtInputString.Text.Length;
txtInputString.Focus();

int vowelCount = 0, consonants = 0, nonNumeric = 0; 
int count = txtInputString.TextLength;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if ((txtInputString.Text.Contains('a') == true) || (txtInputString.Text.Contains('e') == true) || (txtInputString.Text.Contains('i')== true) || (txtInputString.Text.Contains('o')==true) || (txtInputString.Text.Contains('u')==true))
    {
        vowelCount++;
    }
    else if ((txtInputString.Text.Contains('b') == true) || txtInputString.Text.Contains('c') || txtInputString.Text.Contains("d") || txtInputString.Text.Contains("f") || txtInputString.Text.Contains("g"))
    {
        consonants++;
    }
    else
    {
        nonNumeric++;
    }
}
txtVowel.Text = vowelCount.ToString() + "";
txtConsonant.Text = consonants.ToString() + "";

txtNonNumeric.Text = nonNumeric.ToString();
```

Comment: You're looking at the entire text every loop.

Comment: You can debug your application step by step to understand your mistake... Tip: you are using for loop, but you are not iterating inside it any collection

Comment: `(txtInputString.Text.Contains('a') == true)` sure? Better check `((txtInputString.Text.Contains('a') == true) == true)`. :P -- But seriously, you might want to have a `var vowels = HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }` and then check `if (vowels.Contains(txtInputString.Text[i]) { vowelCount++; }`. and similar for consonants.

Comment: Also, why is the last counter named `nonNumeric`? If the input is `"a1a"`, then `'1'` would be counted as `nonNumeric`, which would be weird. And you don't need the `+ ""` in `txtVowel.Text = vowelCount.ToString() + "";` and the next line.

Comment: The [Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Char_methods.aspx) class has some pretty nice methods to determine, if a char [is a digit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) or [is a letter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.char.isletter.aspx). Sadly no `IsVowel`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
    txtInputString.SelectionStart = 0;
    txtInputString.SelectionLength = txtInputString.TextLength;
    txtInputString.Focus();
    int vowelCount = 0, consonants = 0, nonNumeric = 0; 
    int count = txtInputString.TextLength;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        char c = txtInputString.Text.ElementAt(i);

        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
            vowelCount++;
        else if (c == 'b' || c =='c' || c == 'd' || c == 'f')
            consonants++;
        else
            nonNumeric++;
    }
    txtVowel.Text = vowelCount.ToString() + "";
    txtConsonant.Text = consonants.ToString() + "";

    txtNonNumeric.Text = nonNumeric.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make this a lot more simple by loading up all your consonants and vowels beforehand and applying some LINQ:

```
string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
string vowels = "aeiou";
int vowelCount = 0, consonantCount = 0, nonNumericCount = 0;

var input = "alsdkghanivhusrvndb";  //some input         

foreach (char t in input)
{
   if (consonants.Any(c => c == t))
       consonantCount++;
   else if (vowels.Any(c => c == t))
       vowelCount++;
   else
       nonNumericCount++;
}
```